How get the value of a 'charset' meta element with Xpath?
With Selenium webdriver, I'm trying to parse  a charset meta element from a page.
<meta charset="UTF-8">

This is what I have so far
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

xpath='//meta[@charset]'
charset_meta_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)

I get a WebElement object.
How from this element I can get the value (eg: 'UTF-8')?

You can use the get_attribute() method like so.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("file:///index.html")  # Replace with the actual path

xpath = '//meta[@charset]'
charset_meta_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)

# Get the value of the charset attribute
charset_value = charset_meta_element.get_attribute("charset")
print("Charset:", charset_value)

driver.quit()


You can use get_attribute to get value.
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

xpath='//meta[@charset]'
charset_meta_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, XPath)

charset = charset_meta_element.get_attribute("charset")

